# SDL Window will not show even though I have a working event loop on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, window, sdl, sdl-2

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. When I look up my issue, almost all the answers are solved by adding an event loop. I have an event loop already and I know its working because I used cout in my input function and it just filled up the terminal. I almost feel like the issue is related to the Ubuntu I'm running, maybe because I'm running it on a Gen 1 Surface Book. That being said, I updated my Mesa to 20.3.0 and my computer is compatible with OpenGL 4.6 so maybe that's not it.

Anyways this is the code I have. The program compiles with no issues, and it runs. The only issue is that the window does not show up on the screen. PS, I've also already tried calling `SDL_SetMainReady();` right before the `SDL_Init()`

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

// Globals
int gScreenWidth = 640;
int gScreenHeight = 480;
SDL_Window* gWindow = nullptr;
SDL_GLContext gContext = nullptr;

bool gQuit = false; // if true we quit

void InitializeProgram(){
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
        std::cout << "SDL2 could not initialize video subsystem" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 6);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL First Program", 0, 0, gScreenWidth, gScreenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if(gWindow == nullptr){
        std::cout << "SDL Window could not be created" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    gContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(gWindow);
    if(gContext == nullptr){
        std::cout << "OpenGL Context could not be created" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

void Input(){
    SDL_Event e;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
        if(e.type == SDL_QUIT){
            std::cout << "Goodbye!" << std::endl;
            gQuit = true;
        }
    }
}

void PreDraw(){

}

void Draw(){

}

void MainLoop(){
    while(!gQuit){
        Input();
        PreDraw();
        Draw();
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(gWindow); // Updates the screen
    }
}

void CleanUp(){
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(){
    InitializeProgram();

    MainLoop();

    CleanUp();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. The program works (after I replace `while(SDL_PollEvent(...))` with `if(SDL_WaitEvent(...))`).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Must be something with my machine then, which is going to be way harder to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Try SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN ~

```
 SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Basic C++ SDL project",
                                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                          SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                                          SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

Comment: If OP is using GL, this should be `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN`. I doubt it'll help though.

Comment: Still no window. But according to their documentation SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN is ignored by SDL_CreateWindow because the window is implicitly shown if SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN is not set.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I tried that too and it didn't work still.

Comment: You want SDL_WaitEvent, not SDL_PollEvent.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Just tried that, still no window popping up.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested using your code and [sample](https://github.com/cbush-old/sdl2-examples/blob/master/glcontext.cpp)

- Window pop ups
- Used a triangle sample from source and combined all into main

On my machine major & minor versions failed even though they re correct - failed to create context so removed.

SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL made the window visible.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <iostream>

// Define MAX and MIN macros
#define MAX(X, Y) (((X) > (Y)) ? (X) : (Y))
#define MIN(X, Y) (((X) < (Y)) ? (X) : (Y))

// Define screen dimensions
#define SCREEN_WIDTH    800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT   600


// Globals
int gScreenWidth = 640;
int gScreenHeight = 480;
SDL_Window* gWindow = nullptr;
SDL_GLContext gContext = nullptr;

bool gQuit = false; // if true we quit


int main(){
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
        std::cout << "SDL2 could not initialize video subsystem" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL First Program", 0, 0, 
            gScreenWidth, gScreenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    gContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(gWindow);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION|GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-320, 320, 240, -240, 0, 1);

    if(gWindow == nullptr){
        std::cout << "SDL Window could not be created" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if(gContext == nullptr){
        std::cout << "OpenGL Context could not be created" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_Event e;
    float x = 0.0, y = 30.0;

    while (!gQuit)
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(&e);

        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            gQuit = true;

        glClearColor(0,0,0,1);          // Draw with OpenGL.
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   
        glRotatef(10.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);     
        // Note that the glBegin() ... glEnd() OpenGL style used below is actually 
        // obsolete, but it will do for example purposes. For more information, see
        // SDL_GL_GetProcAddress() or find an OpenGL extension loading library.
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);          
          glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex2f(x, y+90.0);
          glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0); glVertex2f(x+90.0, y-90.0);
          glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0); glVertex2f(x-90.0, y-90.0);
        glEnd();

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(gWindow);
        SDL_Delay(10);
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(gContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you compiling your file? Also when I try your code I get errors when compiling in reference to the OpenGL code. "undefined reference to glLoadIdentity()" etc